# For what value of $\alpha$ does the series $\sum(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\times\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(k))$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't see how i can find an equivalent to the sequence, I have tried using Bertrand series.

Comment: Use [Stirling formula](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Stirling). Observe that $\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)=\ln(n!)$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron and for the problem at hand, I think that ${\sqrt n}^{n-\sqrt n}\le n! \le n^n$ is good enough

Comment: thanks using the second inequality i managed to use bertrand's series and show that $\alpha$ must be be bigger than 2

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about Riemann sums? If so, you know that, as $n\rightarrow+\infty$,  $$\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left ( \frac k n\right) \rightarrow \int_0^1\ln x dx=-1$$

Since $\ln \frac k n = \ln k - \ln n$, you can rewrite that as $$\left (\frac 1 {n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k\right) - \ln n \rightarrow -1$$
And thus
$$\left (\frac 1 {n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k\right)\sim\ln n$$
This implies that
$$\frac 1 {n^\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k \sim \frac {\ln n}{n^{\alpha - 1}}$$
So your series converge iff $\alpha > 2$.